# PWA:dynamically load javascript files synchronous from local cache

Tags: javascript, caching, progressive-web-apps

as the title suggests i would like to load js files from local cache, but unfortunatelly it has to be in a synchronous manner. I have built a PWA app, and ideally,i would like to use the service worker cache, to store all my js resources, locally. I have already set up web caching, but it seems that from time to time, the app cache on the phone,gets deleted, and all the resources have to be retrieved from the server all over again. This must be a PWA limitation from what i understand(its happening both in andoid and iPhones).

So in order to solve this issue, i decided to use the local cache my self, by taking advantage of the service worker cache. However there is an issue with this approach, since i am also adding a lot of js files dynamically, when they are needed using XMLhttprequest in a synchronous manner. Moreover the service worker seems to not intercept synchrounous ajax calls, hence these files dont get cached.

I have many files written in the following manner:

```
ImportJS("MyJSClassFile");
MyJSClass.SomeFunction();
//MyJSClass is inside MyJSClassFile
```

The *ImportJS* function is mine, which loads js files from the server using XMLhttprequest synchronously. I am fully aware that my design is not good, but unfortunatelly i have far too many files done this way, to go back and rewrite the code.

From my research, it seems that i should replace my XMLhttprequest with the Fetch API. However this runs asynchronously. Which means that a lot of my code will break.

So my question is, is there a way to store my js files in the local cache(prefarably service worker cache but indexedDB could work too) and then load them  synchronously? From what i understand this is not possible, but i would like to hear your opinions.

I tried my best to make my question clear enough!

p.s.:i have been searching online for a solution for two days now, before posting here, so please be jentle. I have already banned from stackoverflow once, for not posting a question according to the site's standards in the past, so if this question falls out of the requested guidelines, i would appreciate some remarks before the ban.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PWA Cache refresh page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56972132/pwa-cache-refresh-page) Also see: [Service worker caching and HTTP caching](https://web.dev/service-worker-caching-and-http-caching/)

Comment: Hey @Yogi. Thanks for your response! I read both the stackoverflow question and the article. To be honest it didn't add something new to my knowledge base. I have been reading about this issue for the past couple of days.  I m not looking to caching all my files in advance, since i load js files on-demand, when the code requires it. More over i need to do this in a synchronous manner, which is prohibited by the default design of the service worker cache mechanism. Thanks any way!